# Is there a way to automate the return key after a linux script command?

Tags: linux, shell, key, return

I am using the line below in my script
`add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`
When it is run from the script I get a prompt to press [return] to confirm adding the source to the repositories

Can I automate that return?

Secondly, I am installing oracle-java7-installer and there is a license agreement that prompts for the user to:
1.. OK the License agreement
2.. select YES to Accept License Terms

Can I automate the OK and automate the keypad left & OK to Accept License Terms?
This script is for testing locally and I do want the script to pause for these user inputs each time.

I have seen this method of piping YES to a command:
`yes | <command here>`

I am hoping there is a similar method to automate these steps...

Comment: `add-apt-repository` has an interesting `-y` option..

Comment: Why not just use yes,as you stated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `echo` will produce a new line!

Answer (score 2):

For `add-apt-repository` you can use the `-y` flag to skip the yes/no prompt.

The Oracle Java one is a little more complicated, but this will do what you want:

```
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | sudo debconf-set-selections

# Install required packages
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer -y
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.. Sorry it took so long to get back. Your Answer worked perfectly..